# How to query OpenStreetMap data served by GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, openlayers, query-layer

We have a specific point and would like to count all features in a circular area with center at that specific point.

The data is:

- Stored in a shapefile layer created in QGIS
- Served by GeoServer
- Browsed by a web browser using OpenLayers

Comment: do you have a spatial database (like postgres/postgis)?

Comment: Yes, but I think it's not what I need in this case, as the features are all in shapefiles.

Comment: Yes but why you just dont put those shapefiles in a db and query over that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue a WFS-hits request with a specific [ECQL](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/filter/ecql_reference.html#filter-ecql-reference) filter (maybe DWITHIN)

```
Example request
http://<server>/wfs/?&version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=ns:layer&resultType=hits&CQL_FILTER=<ECQL FILTER>
```

The response is something like

```
<wfs:FeatureCollection numberOfFeatures="324" timeStamp="2013-02-08T18:18:28.649Z" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/wfs http://schemas.opengis.net/wfs/1.1.0/wfs.xsd"/>
```